# Python - Getting a recursive list of directory and subdirectory

Tags: python

I would like to get a list of tuple containing every directory and their sub-directories, for instance, with a tree like this:

```
-A
---AA
---AB
-----ABA
-----ABB
-B
---BA
---BB
```

I would get a list looking like this:

```
[
    (A, [
            (AA, []),
            (AB, [
                     (ABA, []),
                     (ABB, []),
                 ]),
        ]),
    (B, [
            (BA, []),
            (BB, []),
        ]),
]
```

I am not interested about the files.

I tried using *os.walk('.')*, but I didn't manage to get inside the directories before moving to the next entry.

Any idea ?

Comment: You can use recursion here.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Isn't os.walk() already recursive?

Comment: Print the triple (I mean the tuple with three values) that os.walk returns in each iteration; if you understand the data os.walk gives you, you'll have no problem using it.

Comment: Yes, but the point is more how you will store it in a list, so instead of using `os.walk(..)` you can do the recursion yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can obtain a list of the *immediate* subdirectories with:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isdir

subdirs = [join(d, o) for o in listdir(d) if isdir(join(d,o))]
```

We can use this in a recursive way with:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isdir

def obtain_subdir_tuples(d):
    subdirs = [join(d, o) for o in listdir(d) if isdir(join(d,o))]
    return (d, [obtain_subdir_tuples(subdir) for subdir in subdirs])
```

A potential problem with this is however that we can also follow symbolic links and get stuck in infinite recursion: a symbolic link in a directory that points to the parent (or an anchestor in general) of that directory. In that case the directory is thus a child of itself somehow. We can avoid this by first looking whether it is a symbolic link with `islink`:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, isdir, islink

def obtain_subdir_tuples(d):
    subdirs = [join(d, o)
               for o in listdir(d)
               if isdir(join(d, o)) and not islink(join(d, o))]
    return (d, [obtain_subdir_tuples(subdir) for subdir in subdirs])
```

Comment: Thanks, even better with the symlink problem solved.